# Explain the formula of energy in signal processing

Tags: integration, signal-processing

Please, give me intuitive understanding of this formula (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_%28signal_processing%29):

[image: Signal x of t]

So **t** is time, **x(t)** - signal function, integral is sum of this function on the whole x-axis, but: 
 
why we need square ? 
what does mean **dt** (why not **dx**) ?

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/886012/81360)

Comment: You might be used to having $ x $ be the input to the function we're integrating, like $\int f (x) dx $. But in this case $ x $ is the name of a function, and the input is $ t $.  Hence $ dt $ rather than $ dx $.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom littleO: thanks, I've understood what dt is.
And what is geometric interpretation of squaring signal function?

Comment: what i wanted: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/7929/204563